# Error in read.table with colClasses

Tags: r, read.table

I would read a text file (using read.table) which contains a column among three with characters like "000000" but I get 0 instead. I try with:

```
X<-read.table(ouvrefic, header=TRUE, row.names=1, sep="",colClasses=c("integer","character","factor"))
```

and I get:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
scan() expected 'an integer', got '"1"' (problem comes from row.names, I suppose)
```

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot.

Beginning of my text file:

```
"" "dates" "Atscan2" "pqrPQR"
"1" "18369" "0000000000000" "1110"
"2" "18369" "0000000000000" "1220,0"
"3" "18369" "0000000000000" "2220"
"4" "18369" "0000000000000" "1230,0,0"
"5" "18369" "0000000000000" "1330,0"
"6" "18369" "0000000000000" "2330,0"
"7" "18369" "0000000000000" "3330"
```

Comment: Can you show us a portion of the file (first few lines)?

Comment: "" "dates" "Atscan2" "pqrPQR"
"1" "18369" "0000000000000" "1110"
"2" "18369" "0000000000000" "1220,0"
"3" "18369" "0000000000000" "2220"
"4" "18369" "0000000000000" "1230,0,0"
"5" "18369" "0000000000000" "1330,0"
"6" "18369" "0000000000000" "2330,0"
"7" "18369" "0000000000000" "3330"

Comment: Please edit it into your question so we can see the formatting appropriately.

Comment: @Lio May be this link would be helpful http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/read-table-with-quoted-integers-td4677249.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `colClasses` argument:

First of all you have 4 columns even if you will use the first one as `row.names`. Therefore, you need four elements in that vector.

And second you if you need all of the zeros to show properly you need to have that column as character.

The following works:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text='"" "dates" "Atscan2" "pqrPQR"
"1" "18369" "0000000000000" "1110"
"2" "18369" "0000000000000" "1220,0"
"3" "18369" "0000000000000" "2220"
"4" "18369" "0000000000000" "1230,0,0"
"5" "18369" "0000000000000" "1330,0"
"6" "18369" "0000000000000" "2330,0"
"7" "18369" "0000000000000" "3330"', 
row.names=1, 
colClasses=c('character', 'character',"character","factor"))
```

Output:

```
> df
  dates       Atscan2   pqrPQR
1 18369 0000000000000     1110
2 18369 0000000000000   1220,0
3 18369 0000000000000     2220
4 18369 0000000000000 1230,0,0
5 18369 0000000000000   1330,0
6 18369 0000000000000   2330,0
7 18369 0000000000000     3330
```

The problem as you can see above is that if a column's elements are quoted (like the dates column) then having an `integer` option in `colClasses` will not work (and therefore I converted that to character as well). You can always use `as.integer` afterwards and convert it to integer.

A direct solution is provided by Akrun in the comments which would remove the double quotes read from `readLines` first and then apply the `colClasses` on the  columns:

```
 df <- read.table(text=gsub('[\\"]', '', readLines('ouvrefic.txt')),
                  row.names=1, 
                  colClasses=c('character', 'integer', 'character', 'factor'))
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `dates` column be `integer` as suggested in the OP's post?

Comment: @akrun Yeah, that is what I wanted to do but it seems to fail if you specify it as `integer` because of the double quotes around the date column's elements. You can do it after the `df` has been formed though.

Comment: One option might be `df <- read.table(text=gsub('[\\"]', '', readLines('ouvrefic.txt')), row.names=1, colClasses=c('character', 'integer', 'character', 'factor'))`, not sure if this useful or not

Comment: @akrun Will work Akrun. I would post it as a solution if I were you.

Comment: You can update this as an option.  My solution is not that elegant to post as a new solution :-)

Comment: @akrun Thanks Akrun. I still think it is a great solution though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `NA` in `colClasses` when `row.names = 1`

```
writeLines('"" "dates" "Atscan2" "pqrPQR"
"1" "18369" "0000000000000" "1110"
"2" "18369" "0000000000000" "1220,0"
"3" "18369" "0000000000000" "2220"
"4" "18369" "0000000000000" "1230,0,0"
"5" "18369" "0000000000000" "1330,0"
"6" "18369" "0000000000000" "2330,0"
"7" "18369" "0000000000000" "3330"', "x.txt")

df <- read.table("x.txt", header = TRUE, 
     row.names = 1, colClasses = c(NA, NA, "character", NA))

sapply(df, class)
#      dates     Atscan2      pqrPQR 
#  "integer" "character"    "factor" 
df
#   dates       Atscan2   pqrPQR
# 1 18369 0000000000000     1110
# 2 18369 0000000000000   1220,0
# 3 18369 0000000000000     2220
# 4 18369 0000000000000 1230,0,0
# 5 18369 0000000000000   1330,0
# 6 18369 0000000000000   2330,0
# 7 18369 0000000000000     3330
```

Also, if you're on a Linux-based, you can remove all the quotes with `system()` and make it a little bit easier

```
read.table(
    text = system("cat x.txt | tr -d \\\"", intern = TRUE), 
    colClasses = c(Atscan2 = "character")
)
#   dates       Atscan2   pqrPQR
# 1 18369 0000000000000     1110
# 2 18369 0000000000000   1220,0
# 3 18369 0000000000000     2220
# 4 18369 0000000000000 1230,0,0
# 5 18369 0000000000000   1330,0
# 6 18369 0000000000000   2330,0
# 7 18369 0000000000000     3330
```